How can I get debug output without ellipsis?
I just can't seem to get debug output without these ellipsis;)
For example, if I try the command lsp-show-references

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "The connected server(s) does not support method te...")
  error("The connected server(s) does not support method %s..." "textDocument/references")
  lsp--send-request-async((:jsonrpc "2.0" :method "textDocument/references" :params (:textDocument (:uri "file:///mnt/c/share/pl...") :position (:line 84 :character 25) :context (:includeDeclaration t))) #f(compiled-function (res) #<bytecode 0x1edfed2336054d26>) detached #f(compiled-function (err) #<bytecode -0x19956b7c0fbd0a43>) nil nil :sync-request)
  funcall-interactively(lsp-find-references nil)
  call-interactively(lsp-find-references nil nil)
  command-execute(lsp-find-references)


I've tried to verify all related variables:
print-length, Its value is nil
print-level, Its value is nil
eval-expression-print-length, Its value is 0
eval-expression-print-level Its value is 0



My config also includes
;default 12
(setq eval-expression-print-length 0)
;default 4
(setq eval-expression-print-level 0)

(setq backtrace-verbose t)
(setq debugger-args '("--no-debugger-ellipsis"))



Any other ideas I can try?;)

This is a duplicate: there are separate edebug- variables that need to be set.

N.B. if you want unlimited, set them all to nil, not 0.

You basically posted the same question with the same misunderstanding of 0 vs nil seven months ago.

This question is similar to: How to expand truncated information displayed in the echo area?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
